# Font Size Bug in Safari on Mac device

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-size

A client I have has this weird font-size issue in Safari on his High Sierra device that I can't seem to replicate on any device (it's literally only happening to him). The fonts appear to be much larger pretty much everywhere on the homepage (that's all I have screenshots of). I've tried increasing my system font size and it definitely doesn't do what his screenshot does.

Basically, the site looks like this on his end
[image: Basically, the site looks like this on his end]

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is happening since I can't replicate it. Has anybody experienced a similar issue?

Here's the site in question: http://rescomrailing.com/

Comment: Look what font-size your client has set in their browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the user has not turned on some kind of text zoom either in Safari or in the Mac OS. If that's not it, have them look at the same page in a new "Private Window" on Safari to see if the text is the same. Maybe try to get them to completely clear their cache.

Comment: Yes. This would be the direction i would take as well.